# Two distinct types of users want to view same routes but expecting different returns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two distinct types of users that want to use the same RESTful routes. I have a polymorphic association between users and profiles, and the two types of profiles are `PatientProfile` and `DoctorProfile`. What I'm trying to do is to come up with a clean way for both user types to be able to use the same controller actions.

```
class User
  belongs_to :profile, polymorphic: true

class PatientProfile
  has_one :user, as: :profile

class DoctorProfile
  has_one :user, as: :profile
```

I have a `Review` model.

```
# reviews_controller.rb
def index
  # for patients this would be all reviews they wrote
  # for doctors it would be all reviews about them
  current_user.reviews
end
```

I've taken care to run everything off of the user instead of the profile because I thought it would be cleaner. However now I'm thinking the `current_user` method should really returning the profile instead of just the user. All associations should then be made in the respective profile model.

My question: Am I thinking about this the correct way or am I missing something? I looked into `CanCanCan` and `Pundit` but both seem to be for allowing specific actions whereas I'm trying to return distinct information based on who is requesting it.

Comment: This looks fine to me. What's the question?

Comment: Are the Profiles exactly the same other than their names?

Comment: @Ninigi not exactly. For example a doctor `has_one :specialty`. A patient `has_one: insurance` whereas a doctor `has_many :accepted_insurances`